# Can you order branches in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branch

I cannot find any discussions around how to order branches in TFS. More specifically how to change the "View Order" in which the branches show in Visual Studio. It seems that Visual Studio 2019 orders the branches in an alphabetical order. How can I change that?

Currently the order is like so

-- Repository

- CPAngular
- DEV
- Development-Angular
- Development-Sandbox
- LIVE
- SIT
- Tools
- UAT
- UITests

I would like to see them in this order

-- Repository

- DEV
- SIT
- UAT
- LIVE
- CPAngular
- Development-Angular
- Development-Sandbox
- UITests
- Tools

Update: This questions relates to a TFS (Team Foundation Server) repository, accessed through Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I guess you use Git, right?

Comment: No tfs as stated in the tags.

Comment: TFS is supports git, maybe you mean to TFVC

Comment: Hi BNg, Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. It's simply not able to change/update the order of created branch in Visual Studio IDE. I would suggest you to use the build-in or some other tools to view/manage branch hierarchy.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk touche, I am in fact talking about TFVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it is not able to do this.

Just the same as files/folders created which simple **alphabetical**  in the Visual Studio IDE.

It's not able to change the order either ascend/descend or manually drag.

Besides, instead of view branch in this kind of view order, we suggest you to [View the branch hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/view-branch-hierarchy-team-project?view=azure-devops) of a project

[image]

Comment: I can't see the same functionality being available from the "Hierarchy View" and the "Source Control Explorer" If I could have the Hierarchy view instead of the sidebar in the Source Control Explorer it would be nice but ideally I just want to be able to reorder the view. I guess the "Extreme" way to do it is to name the branches 1.Dev 2.Test 3.UAT 4.LIVE

Comment: @BNg Yeah, thanks for your kindly sharing. Re-name the branch should be a workaround in your case. Sorry for any inconvenience, it's not able to reorder the view in Source Control Explorer at present. This is controlled by Visual Studio.